# How to make a class diagram for a django project?

Tags: python, django, uml, class-diagram

I have this Django project that contains several applications , each one contains (apps, models, forms, views, urls, tests) files. the question is what is the structure I should follow to design the class diagram for this and what are the relations among the apps?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. I'd recommend to sit back and read a few books first.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I know how to make a class diagram for regular projects, but I have not worked with a project with model-views-forms structure before. and it doesn't seem to be any resources available for such a thing.

Comment: There is. Be assured. Just a google for MVC will flood you with examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For someone new to the system, it's not uncommon to want an architectural overview and in general docs are lacking in that respect, so I understand why you're asking.

As Thomas mentions, Django follows the MVC pattern, except that your controllers are your URLs and to some extent, Middlewares and WSGI interface.

Your initial design should focus on models. Models will contain all the business logic. Views gather the information from the models and urls combined with forms pass user information to views.

But the application's heart are it's models, so good class diagrams of the models (and a good model design) will allow you to see what the project can and can't do and how it's done.

For an example, take a look at [Mezzanine's model graph](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/model-graph.html), which is a CMS written on top of Django. And it's model graph is [autogenerated](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/utils/docs.py#L236).

Comment: oh thank you for explanation it made it a little bit clear, all I was thinking about is making a detailed class diagram , which means design all files structure inside an app box and link the apps together.

Comment: As the project grows, views may become more important. But their structure is pretty much the same throughout. However, it does help to have a class diagram of the so-called "mixins" you use in views, so others know what to "mix in" to get the components of a page they need.